# How to reduce code in Swift when dealing with variables and if statements?

Tags: swift, xcode, variables, swift5

I am currently building an app to teach myself Swift so am still very new. I’ve encountered a problem. The app is a timetable creator. I have up to twelve subjects that all have points. These points are then spread across days. I have a concept for code that will allocate the points fine using loops but wondered whether there was something to reduce the amount of code rather than, what I currently have, something like this for each subject:

```
subject1.monpts = 20
subject1.tuepts = 20
subject1.wedpts = 20
subject1.thurpts = 20
subject1.fripts = 20
subject1.satpts = 20
subject1.sunpts = 20
```

This, x12, is a lot of code. But I need it so that each subject has an option for points for each day of the week (which the app will then allocate time based on these points). To print the timetable, I am putting each subjectX.daypts together but this means I’m writing out 12 subjects for each day.

I also need to only display something if the variable actually has a value. I plan to do this using if statements but that means writing a statement for every single variable which at the moment is 12 x 7 = 48! E.g. (ignore the formating - just for concept)

```
    if subjects1.monpts = 0 {
        subjects1monLabel = isHidden.false
        // or just a print / don't print statement
    }
```

I feel as if I'm missing an easier way to do this!

Here is a picture that explains the concept a bit better:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save information about those fields you can have a dictionary with keys of a enum and values of ints like so:

```
enum WeekDay: CaseIterable {
    case monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday
}

struct Subject {
    var pointsForWeekDay: [WeekDay: Int]
}
```

Now you could do:

```
var pointsForWeekDay = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
    WeekDay.allCases.map { weekDay in
        return (weekDay, 20)
    }
)
var subject = Subject(pointsForWeekDay: pointsForWeekDay)
```

`CaseIterable` allows you to access all values of your enum.

`Map` takes every weekDay and creates an array of tuples with your Int values.

And finally you can combine that to have a complete `Dictionary` with `uniqueKeysWithValues` initializer, which takes an array of the produced tuples.

Comment: And as a beginner in Swift, I suggest taking a look at [this] (https://www.raywenderlich.com/9222-an-introduction-to-functional-programming-in-swift) or [this] (https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/) article, where concepts such as `map` (, `filter`, `reduce`, etc.) are explained.

Also, @Simon Moshenko, I like your way using CaseIterable!

Answer (score 0):

Your whole vision of how to organize this material is upside down. Start by thinking about what all your subjects have in common: points for each of the seven days, label hidden for each of the seven days, and so forth. Now incorporate that into a type (a struct): Subject. Now instead of `subjects1...`, `subjects2...` and so forth, you have an Array of Subject.

So: any time you have variables named with a number, that should be an array instead. Any time you have clumps of repeated concepts, that should be a type instead.

Even the notion of the seven days of the week could itself be condensed in the same way. If all we're talking about is points per day, an array of seven numbers would do.

So we'd end up with a skeleton like this:

```
struct Subject {
    var dayPoints : [Int]
}
var myTwelveSubjects : [Subject]
```

...and you can build that out as more requirements come online, such as whether a day is hidden.

Comment: and if there are always 20 pts per day for a subject, you could populate the array providing a default value:   `var dayPoints : [Int] = Array(repeating: 20, count: 7)`